# Angular testing on mobile using ng serve with allowed access to all devices on the same network stops working

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular14

I run my app on my desktop using

```
ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=4200 --disable-host-check
```

after that I can access my app in my mobile device. But after a way the app stops loading. Leaving only that bar that appears on top of angular applications loaded until about 70% and doesn't load the page never. It is not a network problem because if I access my machine on a different port... say 168.192.0.x:80 the apache server loads normally. Its an Angular problem I am pretty sure. Someone know about this issue, and how to solve it?

Comment: it is hard to say without debugging. maybe your app code contains logic not supported by mobile devices?

Comment: @Andrei No, it loads and stops working always.

Comment: most likely there are some errors happening. you should debug the application. there is plenty of guides on how to do that